# need help in custom join query in zend framework 2

Tags: zend-framework

I am confused with zend 2 join query with multiple column display, and unable to display those column

**StudTable.php**

```
public function custom_query() {
        $select = new Select();
        $select->from(array('s' => 'stud'));
        $select->columns(array('s.id','a.artist', 's.name', 's.sem','s.age'));
        //$select->where(array('id' => 14));

        $select->join(array('a' => 'album'),
                    'a.id = s.album_id');
        $select->order('s.id DESC'); 
        $select->limit(5);

        return $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);
    }
```

**index.phtml**

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($this->customeObject as $obj_cus) : ?>
        <li>ID: <?php echo $obj_cus->id?>| Artist: <?php echo $obj_cus->artist?> | Name:<?php echo $obj_cus->name?> | Sem:<?php echo $obj_cus->sem?> | Age:<?php echo $obj_cus->age?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
```

but it shows below error 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$select = new Select();
$select->from(array('s' => 'stud'));
/* Select columns from primary table without prefix table */
$select->columns(array('id', 'name', 'sem', 'age'));

/* If need where */
$select->where(array('s.id' => 14));

/* It's a INNER JOIN */
$select->join(
    array('a' => 'album'),
    'a.id = s.album_id',
    /* Select joined columns */
    array('artist')
);
$select->order('s.id DESC'); 
$select->limit(5);
return $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);
```

Answer (score 1):

The columns method signature looks like this:

```
public function columns(array $columns, $prefixColumnsWithTable = true)
```

So by default prefixColumnsWithTable is enabled.

That's why you're getting the error message:

> Unknown column s.s.id

So the easiest way to fix this is to pass in false as the second parameter to columns:

```
$select->columns(array('s.id','a.artist', 's.name', 's.sem','s.age'), false);
```